Origins of Unit Testing in hardware?
I asked this question on Stack Overflow Discussions, but it does not seem to be receiving responses.
Then it occurred to me that it is in fact suitable for Software Engineering, so here it is.

According to the Wikipedia entry for Unit Testing, it is defined as a technique for testing components of a system in strict isolation from each other, and it is described as having been expressly invented for Software, and having only been applied to Software. In that same Wikipedia entry we read that the first reference to anything even remotely resembling Unit Testing was in a 1956 U.S. Navy Symposium about software, and then again in 1964, in the context of the software developed for NASA's Mercury Project.
However, I once came across a different source, which suggested otherwise.
According to that source, Unit Testing in software is an adaptation of preexisting testing techniques for analog electronic hardware.
This claim sounds plausible, since in electronic hardware, the operation of each component on a PCB is affected by the mere presence of other components on that same PCB, so in order to locate a defect it is of vital importance to test each component in isolation. Additionally, virtually all early computer hardware was analog, and all early programmers were involved with hardware to a greater or lesser degree, (or should I say to a great or greater degree?) so it is reasonable to assume that the first testing methods for software were inspired by existing testing methods for hardware.
Nonetheless, I have to wonder whether this is actually true, and unfortunately, I have forgotten where I first encountered the claim.
So, does this claim ring any bells to anyone?
Can you please help me find the original source of this claim, or otherwise attest, from personal knowledge, that it is in fact true?
What I am essentially looking for is historical references to a systematic approach for testing components (units) of a system in strict isolation from each other, in the context of electronic hardware, before software testing was even a thing. Such an approach would not necessarily be named "Unit Testing", but its aim would have to be the same as the aim of Unit Testing, which is Defect Localization: being able to tell with certainty which unit has a defect, which is impossible when the components are interconnected and therefore interfering with each other.

Here is a discussion corroborating this claim, which though is completely devoid of any references to sources: Reddit.com - When was unit testing first invented?
In the mean time I have gone ahead and repeated this claim in an answer of mine to a question here on Software Engineering, and I do not feel comfortable about the fact that the claim that I have made is not backed by a reference to a source.

next you'll be saying "bugs" means actual bugs!

@Ewan: First actual computer bug

Is there any source that attest for this usage in analog circuits? It's indeed easily claimed, but was it really a formalised practice ? I mean,  complex mechanic devices like the first automobiles probably also had unit test for individual parts and integration tests for making sure that the assembly of parts works as expected. But again, is there any evidence of a systematic practice on the terms used for the various kind of tests? As you know wikipedia requires decent sources for claims like that. If you have valid sources, feel free to amend wikipedia ;-)

@Christophe I am not sure I understand your comment. It seems like your comment is asking the same thing as my question.

Why dont you ask @KentBeck ?

@MikeNakis my comment is that there are no older references to the term "unit testing". The fact that some claim it was done before should come with an historical evidence. At least, this is the standard for wikipedia contributions

TBH, I feel this will mostly come down to your definition of "Unit Test" and "Origin".

Define "hardware". I'm not being facetious here. If a mechanic is told to work on a car that doesn't start, and as part of their investigation they take out a component and try and use it in isolation, that's a unit test. Blowing a tube to find out if it's blocked or not is a unit test. It seems like you're specifically restricting yourself to the field of computing, which is effectively doing the same thing as the Wikipedia article that claims that unit testing was expressly invented for software: setting an arbitrary boundary on the definition of your words. Why only computing?

What I'm trying to get at here is whether you're asking about the term "unit testing" itself (which I do believe was coined in a software context), or the act of testing a component in isolation (which well predates computing).

@Flater I see.  I added a paragraph to the question, to address this.

@MikeNakis: Appreciate the clarification but it needs a reasonable limitation as to what you consider an act of testing. The act of testing things before "real" usages will date back to our primitive roots. Someone making stone arrowheads will have checked that the stones are sharp before affixing them to the shaft of the arrow. People will have tasted an ingredient to vet it, before putting it into a meal. There's unlikely to be a clear origin point with references.

So, I was googling this a lot today.
All the sources agree that the term "Unit Test" was popularised by Kent Beck and means whatever he meant it to mean.
Martin Fowler has an interesting anecdote about working with Kent Beck in the early days of extreme programming however

There were definitional concerns about XP's use of unit testing right
from the early days. I have a distinct memory of a discussion on a
usenet discussion group where us XPers were berated by a testing
expert for misusing the term “unit test.” We asked him for his
definition and he replied with something like “in the first morning of
my training course I cover 24 different definitions of unit test.”

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html
So the idea of "Unit Test" must have been floating around in the days before SUnit and XUnit. I can't find anything about hardware unit tests except for that reddit posts' deleted comment, but with 24 definitions to choose from maybe one was hardware related.

Edit: I see you have updated your question :

What I am essentially looking for is historical references to a
systematic approach to testing components (units) of a system in
strict isolation from each other

This is trivial, for example  : https://quality-one.com/ppap/

The fact that Kent Beck has popularized unit test frameworks is one (recent) thing. Please look at the wikipedia sources for much older references.

If you want to understand the meanings of unit test before the XP movement hijacked the language, you need to look to testing literature - Robert Binder 1999; Boris Beizer 1995, IEEE  1008-1987, Glenford Myers 1979....

I've looked into some of the older docs on testing but couldn't find a reference to "unit testing" or anything that really compared to the modern definition. If you have then you should post an answer

Let's change our perspective on this for once. Testing in general is a way to determine the authenticity of the function of an object, be it a knife or armor from the Medieval Ages, spanning all the way to 21st century technology. Unit testing is a way of ensuring all components of said object work in optimal condition. This will allow further objects in the chain/hierarchy to work accordingly. Unit testing can be dated all the way back to medieval-age armorsmiths, ensuring each link moves at just the right differential in any direction to ensure overall movement. Coming to the point, ensuring every bit of hardware works in the optimal condition will respectively ensure that its corresponding software plays its part. Our technology grows, not only to advance human lives but to also play catch up for all the resources we wasted trying to perfect our technology, leaving us richer in knowledge and poorer in resources.

You made my day. Indeed, and the integration test was the moment where the knight tried his armor out. (and knights are know as being less tolerant for defect of a new  armor)

So what you are essentially saying is that the link between hardware testing and software testing is inevitably there, since they belong to the same continuum of advancing technology, and I agree that it is true, but it is actually so true, as to practically constitute a truism.  What I am looking for is a documented source, like someone admitting, in writing, that they had been doing hardware testing, and then one day they saw for the first time the need to do software testing, and they thought to apply the same methodology.

By this argument, couldn't we go back to checking if a pointy stick is sharp enough  - it may be that unit testing was actually invented by a higher primate.
